# Contact Form 7 stopped working with datalayer push

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I am using the Google Tag manager on my websites. I have the Analytics code inside and event triggers for analytics conversion tracking. I am tracking sent contact forms (kform) from plugin contact form 7. And it stopped working.

I have this in additional settings: `on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event': 'kform'});"`

It dont show the sent successfully message and dont sent the email. Anyone can help? It was working for more than 1 year..

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your tags and triggers that made use of this dataLayer push? With a dataLayer event, you need to create a tag where the *trigger* fires on the exact same event (ie. 'kform').

Comment: Yes I know. It was not working because of not updated Wordpress Core